# Mounting an internal hard drive that was originally formatted as a USB mass storage device

Tags: windows-10, formatting, disk-management

I have an 8TB 3.5" SATA hard drive that I first mounted and formatted on Windows 10 through a [USB to SATA hardware interface](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00MYU0E0K) as an 8TB NTFS partition.

I had to replace a smaller drive inside with this newer drive due to physical space limitations, so I mounted it using that method and transferred data onto it. I then installed it internally via SATA, replacing it with the older drive, but windows 10 can't mount it.

When I examine it in the device manager it says that it is a USB mass storage device rather than a normal hard drive. When I look at it in the Disk Management application (when installed internally via SATA) it sees the drive there as having a 2TB GPT protective partition and 5TB unallocated with no filesystem. It also has all the formatting options grayed out - so I can't even reformat it as NTFS there. When I remount it via the SATA to USB interface, Windows mounts it successfully and the Disk Management tool sees it as a full 8TB NTFS partition.

Is there any way for me to get Windows 10 to be able to mount the drive as an 8tb NTFS partition when installed internally without me having to format it again (and lose the 1.5 days it look to transfer the files)?

If that is not possible, how do I reformat it as as one large NTFS partition, when Disk Management has only grayed out options on that drive now?

Comment: Does it actually have just one partition and 5 TB is unallocated space, or is Windows ignoring everything after the 1st partition because it thinks it's a USB drive?

Comment: I'm not sure - according to the Disk Management tool it says it has that one 2TB partition with 5TB unallocated, but when I mount it via the USB to SATA interface Windows sees the correctly formatted 8TB NTFS partition and I can read/white without issues. So I believe it's Windows being confused because it thinks its a USB drive. I've not found a way to tell it otherwise yet that works.

Comment: What is exactly the disk? The manufacturer might have provided a low-level format utility.

Comment: Seagate BarraCuda 8TB Internal Hard Drive ST8000DM004